# OpenCV Cant load Bitmap (with extra stride bytes) from byte array

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap

I have problem. When I'm loading mat from byte array there is a big problem; extra bytes cause mat to load wrong. If I send byte array ( width: 4-8-12-16-20 etc) It's not a problem because width and stride is equal. But If I byte array with extra stride bytes Image is corrupted. Is there a way to make it right ?

Function that I'm using:

```
Mat bytesToMat(byte * bytes,int height,int width)
{
    Mat image = Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3,bytes).clone(); // make a copy
    return image;
}
```

Example)

23 width image loaded as: [image]

24 width image loaded (Correctly): [image]

Answer (score 1):

The link format was messed up in the comment, so I'll write an answer.

See the constructor `step` and `steps` parameters [in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat). It lets you tell OpenCV how many bytes are in each row (including padding).

You'll also have to check if the byte array you're using as input has any added padding.